General Solutions to Partial Differential Equations with Imaginary Unit
Using the methods introduced in Piaggio's An Elementary Treatise on Differential Equations and Their Applications, I can find that the general solution to the following 2nd order PDE
$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}f(x, y) + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}f(x, y) = 0$
is
$f(x, y) = h_1(x + iy) + h_2(x - iy)$
where $h_1$ and $h_2$ represent arbitrary functions. But this solution contains the imaginary unit $i$. Can we rewrite the above general solution to a form without $i$?
